# Parse cursor output java

Tags: java, linux, cursor

How can i parse the output from a linux cursor program like e.g top in java?
I would like someone to give an example or link one. Right now i got top running like a Process object. And btw top is just an example of such a program.

```
String[] args={"top"};
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A program written using `curses` isn't outputting a stream of characters like a typical command-line program, or even one using the backspace trick. Instead, it's using operating-system specific calls like `ioctl` and implementation-specific escape sequences like those described in [TermInfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo). Generally, such programs on Unix systems are simple frontends to libraries that perform all of the necessary work, and your best option is usually to use those libraries (writing a JNI wrapper if one isn't available).

In the case of `top`, you can see how the program reads the process information from the OS in its source code, available as part of [the procps package](http://procps.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to read all the data that process outputs, which can be done using `Process.getInputStream()` method

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("top").start();
BufferedReader br  =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: This code gives empty BufferedReader, the output cannot be parsed this way

Comment: If the above code is printing nothing.. then the `top` command is not printing the output?

Comment: correct, its probably using some cursor special thing and thats exactly what a want to lean how to parse. Its clearly parse able by  bash since it outputs it to my screen:/ Maybe i could start bash in a Process object and start top from that bash process and get the output?:S

Comment: Another thought i had was to write some C code that parses this output on a lower level and outputs it to stdout. Then start that as a process in java